# How to run docker on mac offline

Tags: macos, docker

When i installed [docker](https://docs.docker.com/mac/step_one/) on mac, it took a ip from my intranet network.
There after when i switched to a different network it was showing me error

```
$ bash --login '/Applications/Docker/Docker Quickstart Terminal.app/Contents/Resources/Scripts/start.sh'
Starting "default"...
(default) Waiting for an IP...
Too many retries waiting for SSH to be available.  Last error: Maximum number of retries (60) exceeded
Regenerate TLS machine certs?  Warning: this is irreversible. (y/n): Regenerating TLS certificates
Detecting the provisioner...
Error getting SSH command: Something went wrong running an SSH command!
command : cat /etc/os-release
err     : exit status 255
output  :
Error checking TLS connection: Something went wrong running an SSH command!
command : ip addr show dev eth1
err     : exit status 255
output  :


                        ##         .
                  ## ## ##        ==
               ## ## ## ## ##    ===
           /"""""""""""""""""\___/ ===
      ~~~ {~~ ~~~~ ~~~ ~~~~ ~~~ ~ /  ===- ~~~
           \______ o           __/
             \    \         __/
              \____\_______/


Error getting IP address: Something went wrong running an SSH command!
command : ip addr show dev eth1
err     : exit status 255
output  :
docker is configured to use the default machine with IP
For help getting started, check out the docs at https://docs.docker.com
```

I understood that something related to the gateway that got configured in 'default'
I ran

```
docker-machine rm default     (this deleted all my previously downloaded images)
docker-machine create --driver virtualbox default
```

Went offline and relaunched docker-machine
The default got built. After that i went online and tried to download a image.
But i was getting connection errors.

```
$ docker run -t -i --name myFirstContainer ubuntu:14.04 /bin/bash
Unable to find image 'ubuntu:14.04' locally
Pulling repository docker.io/library/ubuntu
Network timed out while trying to connect to https://index.docker.io/v1/repositories/library/ubuntu/images. You may want to check your internet connection or if you are behind a proxy.
```

I think its because when i was offline , no interface was assigned to 'default'

```
$ docker network inspect bridge
[
    {
        "Name": "bridge",
        "Id": "df562e1cae477be7d2dc09a30ee21b0871a2202731506d3f6db3df9c1abb4cad",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.17.0.0/16"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Containers": {},
        "Options": {
            "com.docker.network.bridge.default_bridge": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_icc": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_ip_masquerade": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.host_binding_ipv4": "0.0.0.0",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.name": "docker0",
            "com.docker.network.driver.mtu": "1500"
        }
    }
]
```

State when i reconnected to a network and rebuilt 'default'

```
$ docker-machine create --driver virtualbox default
Running pre-create checks...
(default) Default Boot2Docker ISO is out-of-date, downloading the latest release...
(default) Latest release for github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker is v1.10.0
(default) Downloading /Users/tt/.docker/machine/cache/boot2docker.iso from https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/releases/download/v1.10.0/boot2docker.iso...
(default) 0%....10%....20%....30%....40%....50%....60%....70%....80%....90%....100%
Creating machine...
(default) Copying /Users/tt/.docker/machine/cache/boot2docker.iso to /Users/tt/.docker/machine/machines/default/boot2docker.iso...
(default) Creating VirtualBox VM...
(default) Creating SSH key...
(default) Starting the VM...
(default) Waiting for an IP...
Waiting for machine to be running, this may take a few minutes...
Machine is running, waiting for SSH to be available...
Detecting operating system of created instance...
Detecting the provisioner...
Provisioning with boot2docker...
Copying certs to the local machine directory...
Copying certs to the remote machine...
Setting Docker configuration on the remote daemon...

This machine has been allocated an IP address, but Docker Machine could not
reach it successfully.

SSH for the machine should still work, but connecting to exposed ports, such as
the Docker daemon port (usually <ip>:2376), may not work properly.

You may need to add the route manually, or use another related workaround.

This could be due to a VPN, proxy, or host file configuration issue.

You also might want to clear any VirtualBox host only interfaces you are not using.
Checking connection to Docker...
Docker is up and running!
To see how to connect Docker to this machine, run: docker-machine env default

$ docker network inspect bridge
[
    {
        "Name": "bridge",
        "Id": "307267097a1845e6ac7b2a6a67bf800b8cda05f036c649a92af59a44689a55ab",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.17.0.0/16"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Containers": {},
        "Options": {
            "com.docker.network.bridge.default_bridge": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_icc": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_ip_masquerade": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.host_binding_ipv4": "0.0.0.0",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.name": "docker0",
            "com.docker.network.driver.mtu": "1500"
        }
    }
]

$ docker run -t -i --name myFirstContainer ubuntu:14.04 /bin/bash
Unable to find image 'ubuntu:14.04' locally
14.04: Pulling from library/ubuntu
8387d9ff0016: Pull complete
3b52deaaf0ed: Pull complete
4bd501fad6de: Pull complete
a3ed95caeb02: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:0844055d30c0cad5ac58097597a94640b0102f47d6fa972c94b7c129d87a44b7
Status: Downloaded newer image for ubuntu:14.04
```

Is there anyway i can seamlessly run docker even when i am switching networks or when i am offline?

Comment: In my personal experience there were no problems with moving my mac with docker running between networks and when switching it off, so I would expect it normally to work fine. Except for when using [cisco VPN](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/issues/628) or similar solutions. Could this be a potential issue?

Comment: No..its just switching networks. My college network is class B private network & my home network is class C private network